# Boot Freedos 1.2 from PXE Server

Tags: dhcp, pxe, freedos

I have been scouring sources for a while and I can't quite figure out how to boot an old 486 with a new NIC via PXE. What I want to do is boot FreeDos 1.2. During the boot sequence the NIC looks for a boot over DHCP. Now, how I set up a bootable image of FreeDos via DHCP is where I am stuck. Half the battle was finding a modern card to work in this old machine that would allow me to get this far. I have Tftpd32 installed on my Windows 10 machine. How do I go about booting this 486 from either that or a Debian system? Pretty noobish when it comes to network booting. Many thanks.

Comment: You're on the right track.  Tip: You'll also need a TFTP server.  (Conveniently, your DHCP server of choice looks like it will also support TFTP.)  It looks like you're seeking a general guide.  Rather than asking us to post one here, what happens if you use a search engine to look for these details?  Are you seeking some specific information which is being particularly perplexing to find?  (Your question is so general that it sounds like you may not have looked up what DHCP options to set, what to set them to, or how to set up the TFTP server for this.)

Comment: Part of the problem is using the right language to search. You did help me find this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd128762(v=winembedded.51).aspx. So this solves my boot from DHCP questions. Where I am definitely stuck is how to create a boot image of FreeDos1.2. There is a juicy link to that question on this page, but I can't really figure how this applies to my circumstance and how to make the boot image of FD1.2.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily PXE boot FreeDOS with **[Serva](http://vercot.com/%7Eserva/an/NonWindowsPXE3.html#dos)** automated PXE server.

Please use the following ServaAsset.inf

```
;-Serva v3.0 Non-Windows Asset Information File 
;-Boot/Install:
;  FreeDOS 1.0/1.1
;-Tested on:
;  fdboot.img
;-Require:
;  -
;-Notes:
;  -
[PXESERVA_MENU_ENTRY]
asset    = FreeDOS 1.0
platform = x86
kernel_bios   = memdisk
append_bios   = initrd=\NWA_PXE\$HEAD_DIR$\fdboot.img
```

TIP: If you already have a working DHCP server in place (i.e. your Internet router) just set Serva in **proxyDHCP** mode; this way your DHCP server will provide the regular IP/MASK set to the booting client while Serva's proxyDHCP will automatically provide the PXE related booting info in a secondary DHCP transaction.

EDIT 11/01/2021

```
;-Serva v3.0 Non-Windows Asset Information File 
;-Boot/Install:
;  FreeDOS 1.0/1.1/1.2/1.3
;-Tested on:
;  FD13FLOP.IMG (1.3-RC3)
;  FD12LGCY.iso (1.2)
;  fdboot.img   (1.0/1.1)
;-Require:
;  -
;-Notes:
;  -
[PXESERVA_MENU_ENTRY]
asset    = FreeDOS 1.2
platform = x86
kernel_bios   = memdisk
append_bios   = iso initrd=\NWA_PXE\$HEAD_DIR$\FD12LGCY.iso raw

#asset    = FreeDOS 1.3
#platform = x86
#kernel_bios   = memdisk
#append_bios   = initrd=\NWA_PXE\$HEAD_DIR$\FD13FLOP.IMG

#asset    = FreeDOS 1.0
#platform = x86
#kernel_bios   = memdisk
#append_bios   = initrd=\NWA_PXE\$HEAD_DIR$\fdboot.img
```

Not all the flavors distributed work correctly, but the ones mentioned here do

I'm related to Serva development.

Comment: Have been trying this with Freedos 1.2 & 1.3. I think I have tried all the various .img and .iso files. Nothing works, three different errors (one having to do with memory, one "api call failed", and one where it just prints dots and then reboots).